# How to use NLTK DependencyGrammar package In NER

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How to use NLTK DependencyGrammar package in Named Entity Recognition (NER)?

Eg. sentence that I am looking is:
“*what is the status of my invoice P1234U?*”

And I would like to extract P1234U as the invoice number.

Without much training I would like to do this, so no SPACY solution please.

I would prefer to go in a knowledge graph way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For my business need RegEx is also not of much use as the patterns are very diverse in nature. Some idea around POS or Knowledge Graph representation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

NER algorithms are normally trained to recognize well known enities such as places,names etc. P1234U does not fall into any of the well known categories. I would suggest a simple regex search with constraints on max length of the invoice id and check the accuracy on that.